# Move camera on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene in which a collision happens. As soon as the collision happens, I want the camera to pan from object 1 to object 2. I tried to write the code in the collision script, but then I realized that the camera script will always be overriding it, following object 1. So now I'm trying to write it in the camera script but I'm not sure how.

This is my attempt:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject player;
public GameObject player2;

private Vector3 offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}



    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "triggerCube") {
            //SceneManager.LoadScene ("test2");


            transform.position = player2.transform.position + offset;


        }
        else {
            transform.position = player.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. IF a collision happens, transform to player 2's position, but if no collision is happening, stay with player 1. However, c# doesn't allow this void inside a void stuff so I'm hoping someone has a better solution for me?

I can make it work WITHOUT having it contained in a lateupdate, but as far as I understand, having it in lateupdate is pretty essential for camera work.

Comment: Have a GO member variable, call it "targetToFollow" or something and follow that in cam's LateUpdate(). on collision, change the variable's assigned GO to the other object (possibly via a public property). The question is how do you want to apply that change? A cool animation re-focusing to a new target or such, or just swap out followed objects? This solution is for the latter case

Comment: Does it have to be a GO variable? I'm quite new to c# and I haven't worked with those. Your idea is sound, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet for a better understand:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject player1;
public GameObject player2;
public GameObject focusPlayer; //either player1 or player2, initially player1

private Vector3 offset;


private void Start() {
    //could use player1 here as well, it doesn't matter
    offset = transform.position - focusPlayer.transform.position;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject.name == "triggerCube") { //layering? tagging? read up
        focusPlayer = player2;
    } else {
        focusPlayer = player1;
    }
}

private void LateUpdate() {
    transform.position = focusPlayer.transform.position + offset;
}
```

This way, you can add more players, different objects to focus on for the camera, etc, so the whole thing will be much more dynamic and easier to read or maintain.
In case you want smooth camera movement if target was changed, add a float/Vector2-3/wetc member variable and call it (e.g.) "targetOffsetDiff". Whenever the cam gets a new target, set it to the difference between the current target and the new one.
Add an 'if' to LateUpdate() to test the variable's value: if it's non-zero, lerp until it gets (close to) zero and reset it.